# Nancy perform AfterRequest action after OnError

Tags: nancy

I want to add some request timings to the response headers of a request to a Nancy module.  I've added some before/after request handlers into the RequestStartup and added the headers no problem (example below) and all was good.  I've also added an OnError handler to the ApplicationStartup, to catch errors and return a nice formatted Json response.

```
pipelines.BeforeRequest += ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Items.Add("X-RequestStart", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        return null;
    };

pipelines.AfterRequest += ctx =>
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            //Not got around to forcing the culture on the datetime parsing yet...
            var startTime = DateTime.Parse(ctx.Items["X-RequestStart"].ToString());

            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("X-RequestStart", startTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("X-RequestComplete", now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("X-RequestDuration", (now - startTime).ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("X-RequestComplete", now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    };

pipelines.OnError += (ctx, exception) =>
    {
        return ErrorResponse.FromException(exception);
    };
```

What I am noticing however, is that when I have an error thrown, the AfterRequest action is not performed - thus I have no timing headers in to the error response.  I've tried moving the before/after request handling to the application startup, but this has no effect either.

The question is in two parts really, firstly, is it possible to get the framework to perform an AfterRequest action after the OnError action has been performed, or is the pipeline set up in a way to prevent this, and secondly, should these before/after request actions be part of the RequestStartup or ApplicationStartup?  ApplicationStartup seemed sensible for error handling, whereas RequestStartup seemed sensible for interacting with the response headers as it should be on a per request basis, but I'm not sure if there is a convention for this, or if my assumptions were incorrect.

Comment: I have noticed similar behavior on errors. What I've seen is that the context's response property is null. That might be causing your AfterRequest not to run. Just a hint.

Comment: Interesting. I'd not checked that. I am generating a response when the OnError fires, but the response is being set in the OnError delegate, so I guess that isn't getting back into the context.

Comment: Does seem that the context's response property is null - however adding the response back to the context in the OnError doesn't seem to make any difference - I assume this is because the AfterRequest hook has already passed by this point.  Is this a case of me handling the errors badly by placing an action in the OnError, or is there a way around this to keep/add the response to the context?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution - it was a nice to have that was ultimately not required.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not seem possible in NancyFx. I took a detailed look at the source code, specifically `DefaultRequestDispatcher`. `Dispatch` catches any exceptions thrown during route processing, calls `ResolveErrorResult`, then gets the response from the negotiator. There does not appear to be an extensibility point to modify responses generated in this way.

In my opinion, this is an oversight that the developers should consider addressing.

```
public async Task<Response> Dispatch(NancyContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // TODO - May need to make this run off context rather than response .. seems a bit icky currently
    var resolveResult = this.Resolve(context);

    context.Parameters = resolveResult.Parameters;
    context.ResolvedRoute = resolveResult.Route;

    try
    {
        context.Response = await ExecuteRoutePreReq(context, cancellationToken, resolveResult.Before)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        if(context.Response == null)
        {
            context.Response = await this.routeInvoker.Invoke(resolveResult.Route, cancellationToken,
                resolveResult.Parameters, context)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (context.Request.Method.Equals("HEAD", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.Response = new HeadResponse(context.Response);
            }
        }

        await this.ExecutePost(context, cancellationToken, resolveResult.After, resolveResult.OnError)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response = this.ResolveErrorResult(context, resolveResult.OnError, ex);

        if (context.Response == null)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return context.Response;
}

private Response ResolveErrorResult(NancyContext context, Func<NancyContext, Exception, dynamic> resolveResultOnError, Exception exception)
{
    if (resolveResultOnError != null)
    {
        var flattenedException = exception.FlattenInnerExceptions();

        var result = resolveResultOnError.Invoke(context, flattenedException);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return this.negotiator.NegotiateResponse(result, context);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```